# How to make second method parameter required based on first parameter value

Tags: typescript

i am trying to create a class method in which the second parameter needs to be dynamically optional or required depended on first parameter value

**This is my type containing interfaces**:

```
type Settings = {
  AddPaymentInfo: AddPaymentInfo
  AddToCart: AddToCart
  AddToWishlist: AddToWishlist
  CompleteRegistration: CompleteRegistration
  Contact: Contact
  CustomizeProduct: CustomizeProduct
  Donate: Donate
  FindLocation: FindLocation
  InitiateCheckout: InitiateCheckout
  Lead: Lead
  Purchase: Purchase
  Schedule: Schedule
  Search: Search
  StartTrial: StartTrial
  SubmitApplication: SubmitApplication
  Subscribe: Subscribe
  ViewContent: ViewContent
}
```

this is my method in my class

```
  track<T extends keyof Settings>(
    pixelCmd: T,
    settings?: Settings[T]
  ): {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.fbq('track', pixelCmd, settings)
    }
  }
```

With this approach i just solved one problem (make the second parameter to have a type based on first parameter. It is what i ALSO wanted, but now i want to make this second parameter to be required based on some specific properties, lets say for example "Purchase" should be a property that enforces second parameter to be **REQUIRED**

**So if if tried to call this method like shown below, i'd like typescript warn me "expected 2 arguments":**

```
const myClass = new MyClass()

myClass.track('Purchase')
```

**And if i tried to call the method like shown below, considering the property "Lead" is a property that should make the second parameter OPTIONAL, typescript wouldn't complain:**

```
const myClass = new MyClass()

myClass.track('Lead')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a variadic tuple type as the argument of the function and use a conditional to evaluate either to a tuple of length 1 or 2 based on the given key `T`.

```
type Settings = {
  AddPaymentInfo?: string
  AddToCart?: number
  Lead?: boolean
  Purchase: Date
}

function track<T extends keyof Settings>(
    ...args: undefined extends Settings[T] 
      ? [pixelCmd: T, settings?: Settings[T]] 
      : [pixelCmd: T, settings: Settings[T]]
) {}


track("Purchase") // Error: Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2
track("Purchase", new Date())
track("Lead", 2) // Error: type number is not assignable to type boolean | undefined
track("Lead") // Ok
track("Lead", true) // Ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=26&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKBvAUFFAIIAmpACgIYgC2EywAksgGYD2A-AFxTrAAnFKkIlyAFXYBhKgOA8oyAK60ARhAGiAMhCqkFq9uwA2u5KIpKBAYwAWVdBF4ARKsAj4AvvnyslyayR2ZChBKmsAawAecSgIAA93ZFJMCIgQdlZYeCQ0dAA+AApRIgA6ctkMXn9SCFYUCFI4xIYU7IRhdABtcQBdKBKiKE4oLrBEeIhjKVpSXnEAGj4czoU4Drye3v7Bol4xiamZuahF5Y2q9tyMLd78AEo8bx8wyMKAIksbe0d3x4B6f5QACiAgE7AEvBg7Cs1mgPygAEY4qZ6IxCuhHqolMBQpV4FABBAAI5KRBEzAAJnwrwiHy+dgcEHeS2QEAA7lBXO5Cvd7jSBOE6e8dHoWVBKQCgaDwZDQuBoMo1BooIhMMh2LiHOhEKhkFRVKZQux5ZAoIYTGYoAAfKA1OoNUgCoUfUWkP5QQFQADyEWdbxFundS0ESggUp9ESAA)

Comment: I think overloads would be clearer and easier to maintain in case you need to expand upon this.

Comment: It does not have the exact effect i wish. Based on the first property value, i would like to set the second parameter as **OPTIONAL** or **REQUIRED**. In this solution you gave, if i tried to pass a first argument to `track()`  being "Lead" and then i tried to give a second argument, it will cause an error cuz it didnt make the second parameter as **OPTIONAL**. And also the second parameter needs to keep the correct type from types `Settings`, example: if passed "Lead", if i give a second argument, this argument should have same type of `Lead` inside `Settings`. Is it possible?

Comment: I have adapted your solution to this [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oztxlh?file=/index.ts) What you think? Could it be shortened somehow?

Comment: @MatheusSilva - I edited my answer to make it more concise.